# Temporarly Disable PropertyChangedEventHandler To Avoid Infinite Loop

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin

There are two fields. **Field A FromValue** and **Field B ToValue**.

When user inputs a value into Field A, Field B updates.

Update in Field B updates Field A.

When user inputs a value into Field B, Field A updates.

Update in Field A changes Field B.

This creates an infinite loop and ultimately crashes app.

How can I **temporary disable OnPropertyChanged** event so that when value is input in Field A, which in return updates Field B, it does not cause infinite loop?

**The idea is to achieve the following**:

- **When user inputs value into Field A, field B updates but not field A.**
- **When user inputs value into Field B, field A updates but not field B.**

Maybe I'm just going insane.

```
    private string _FromValue{ get; set;}

    public string FromValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _FromValue;
        }
        set
        {
            _FromValue = value;
            ToValue = FromValue + "x";
            OnPropertyChanged("FromValue");
        }
    }

    private string _ToValue { get; set; }

    public string ToValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _ToValue;
        }
        set
        {
            _ToValue = value;
            FromValue = ToValue + "y";
            OnPropertyChanged("ToValue");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the internal field instead of the property when setting the values

```
public string FromValue
{
    get
    {
        return _FromValue;
    }
    set
    {
        _FromValue = value;
        _ToValue = FromValue + "x";
        OnPropertyChanged("FromValue");
        OnPropertyChanged("ToValue");
    }
}

private string _ToValue { get; set; }

public string ToValue
{
    get
    {
        return _ToValue;
    }
    set
    {
        _ToValue = value;
        _FromValue = ToValue + "y";
        OnPropertyChanged("ToValue");
        OnPropertyChanged("FromValue");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I must be really tired to not think of it.